# Volterra equation $y(x)=\cos(x)-x-2+ \int_0^x(t-x)y(t)dt$

Tags: integration, harmonic-functions, integral-equations

Solve the following Volterra integral equation:

> $$y(x)=\cos(x)-x-2+ \int_0^x(t-x)y(t)dt.$$

My attempt so far:

By iterated kernel method we get
\begin{align}
       K_n(x,t) &=\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{(2n-1)!}(t-x)^{2n-1},  \qquad t\le x,\\\\
     K_n(x,t) &=0, \qquad x\le t
     \end{align}

Then it could be solved in a couple of ways:

1. $$y(x)=f(x)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \lambda ^n \int_a^b K_n(x,t)f(t)dt$$
2. $$y(x)=f(x)+\lambda \int_a^b R(x,t,\lambda)f(t)dt$$ where the resolvent is $$R(x,t,\lambda)= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \lambda ^ {n-1} K_n(x,t).$$

In any case, I don't get anything as simple as it could be solvable easily:

I tried to calculate the resolvent:

$$R(x,t,\lambda)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \lambda ^ {n-1} K_n(x,t)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \lambda ^ {n-1} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{(2n-1)!}(t-x)^{2n-1}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \lambda ^k \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!}(t-x)^{2k+1} =  \text{[by wolframalpha. What's the trick?]} =\frac{\sin(\sqrt{\lambda} (t-x))}{\sqrt{\lambda}}.$$ I see that it's going to be a really messy integration further since we have to calculate

$$y(x)=f(x)+\lambda \int_a^b R(x,t,\lambda)f(t)dt \\ = \cos(x)-x-2 + \sqrt{\lambda} \int_t^x \sin \left(\sqrt{\lambda} \left(t-x\right)\right)(\cos(t)-t-2)dt$$

Is there an easier way to solve this problem or is it going to be so problematic?

Comment: The connection to sine in that one line is just that you have a Maclaurin series of sine, after doing a little rearrangement to consolidate the $\lambda^k$ and the $(t-k)^{2k+1}$. That connection should really jump out at you as you look at the expression you got for $K_n$. After that it looks pretty doable, really. You can rewrite $\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}(t-x))$ using an addition formula and then it comes down to a whole bunch of integrals each of which are easy to do.

Answer (score 1):

Just after I posted it, I found the way to solve it...

Just differentiate the whole equation and we get $$y'(x)= - \sin(x)-1-\int_0^x y(t)dt.$$
Differentiate it once again and we get
$$y''(x)=- \cos (x)-y(x) \\ y''(x)+y(x)=- \cos (x)$$ with initial conditions $$y(0)=y'(0)=-1.$$

Now it's an easy PDE problem.

Comment: Yes, that approach will also work in this particular problem; this is a common situation when $K(x,y)=\tilde{K}(x-y)$ and $\tilde{K}$ satisfies some reasonably simple ordinary differential equation, in this case $\tilde{K}''=0$.